# setting state inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to update the state (`tableColumnConfiguration`) inside `useEffect` and then pass on that state to the child component, but this code throws a "Maximum update depth exceeded" error and the app freezes without being able to click anything on screen.

```js
const[environmentTableColumns, setEnvironmentTableCoulmns] = useState(environmentConditionsColumns);

const {
  data: conditionTypeData,
  loading: loadingConditionTypeData,
  errorRedirect: conditionTypeDataErrorRedirect
} = useSectionEnumQuery('conditionType'); // this is API call


useEffect(() => {
  if (conditionTypeData) {
    let data; 
    let updatedEnvironmentColumnConfiguration = environmentConditionsColumns;
    updatedEnvironmentColumnConfiguration = updatedEnvironmentColumnConfiguration.map(item => {
      if (item.dataIndex === 'conditionType') {
        data = conditionTypeData;
      }
      return data
        ? {
          ...item,
          render: text => {
            return renderEnum(text, data);
          }
        }
        : item;
    });
    setEnvironmentTableCoulmns(updatedEnvironmentColumnConfiguration); // here i am setting the state 
  }
}, [conditionTypeData])
```

Child component :

```
<SpaceTypeTable
  values={values}
  isReadOnly={isReadOnly}
  isProjectSystem={isProjectSystem}
  tableTitle="Environment Criteria"
  mappedLibrarySourceArray="environments"
  sourceRender={p => renderGuidelineItem(p, true)}
  tableColumns={environmentTableColumns} // here i am passing the column configuration
  section={MASTER_SECTIONS.LIBRARY_ENVIRONMENT}
  guidelines={guidelines}
  form={form}
  handleWarning={handleWarning}
/>
```

What's causing this `useEffect` loop?

Update :  **UseSectionEnumQuery** :

```
export const useSectionEnumQuery = resultFieldName => {
  const { data: result, loading, error } = useQuery(ENUM_TYPES(resultFieldName));
  const data = result?.[resultFieldName] && sortBy(result[resultFieldName], o => o.label);
  const errorRedirect = error && errorRedirectElement(error, resultFieldName);
  return { loading, data, errorRedirect };
};
```

Comment: It's not necessarily obvious where it's happening, but in cases like this it almost always is setting a state in useeffect triggers a rerender which causes the effect to run again which sets the state again and so on.

Comment: it is because of that useeffect i am getting the above error

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. If you set a state in a useeffect handler that the useeffect handler has in its dependency array, even indirectly, it will run in an infinite render loop.

Comment: i put api result as a dependency for useeffect

Comment: `conditionTypeData` is probably creating a new reference on each render and since it's a dependency in your `useEffect`, it will cause a loop. Can we see your `useSectionEnumQuery` hook?

Comment: @ToddSkelton i just updated question with useSectionEnumQuery hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is causing your problem.

`const data = result?.[resultFieldName] && sortBy(result[resultFieldName], o => o.label);`

`data` will be a new reference each render and it's going to trigger your `useEffect` every render because `data` is `conditionTypeData` and it's in your dependencies.

Can you try memoizing the value, so it only changes when result changes.

```
export const useSectionEnumQuery = resultFieldName => {
  const { data: result, loading, error } = useQuery(ENUM_TYPES(resultFieldName));
  const data = useMemo(() => result?.[resultFieldName] && sortBy(result[resultFieldName], o => o.label), [result, resultFieldName]);
  const errorRedirect = useMemo(() => error && errorRedirectElement(error, resultFieldName), [error, resultFieldName]);
  return { loading, data, errorRedirect };
};
```

Comment: could you please let me know how can i fix that but useSectionEnumQuery is used in many places

Comment: @EnigmaState memoize it with usememo

Comment: Updated with a potential solution